# Angular Js with mysql php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs

Hi I am using angular version 1.5.8.
My aim is to display html content from DB, I'm using ng-bind-html to do this. I'm facing following error
     "angular.js:13920 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- descFilterFilter"

This is my HTML Code:

```
<section id="content" ng-app="homePage" ng-controller='homeController'>
        <div class="container">
            <?php //include("includes/inc-welcome.php"); ?>
                <div ng-bind-html="desc | descFilter"></div>

        </div>
</section>
```

This is my Angular js code for filter controller:

```
app.filter('descFilter', ['$sce','$scope','$http', function ($sce,$scope,$http)
 { 

     $http.get("includes/inc-acc.php").success(function(data)
        {       
            alert(data);
            $scope.desc=$sce.trustAsHtml(data);
          //alert($scope.rwimage.latestnewsimage);     
        })

        //$sce.trustAsHtml($scope.desc);

    }]);
```

This is my php mysql code:

```
<?php 
include ("config.php");

$query = "select latestnewsid, latestnews, latestnewssummary, lattestnewsimage, latestnewsdate from fl_acc where (latestnewsstatus = '1') order by latestnewsdate desc";

$equery = mysql_query($query) or die();
$data1 = array();
while($fetcharray = mysql_fetch_array($equery)) 
{
    $data1[]= $fetcharray;
}
echo json_encode($data1);
?>
```

please help me to resolve this problem...

Comment: Remove your filter `<div ng-bind-html="desc"></div>`

Comment: but how to i define my filter controller in html

Comment: Sorry didn't read your question properly. The `$scope` is available only for controllers and the link function of directives. This is why the filter cannot find it. You should try using `$rootScope`.

Comment: have you any code for ng-bind-html to display html content from DB in html page

Comment: Here is an example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/svigna/HQpQH/). I suggest performing `$http.get` on your controller and not from a filter.